# Disable caret browsing dialog in WinUI 3

Tags: winui-3, winui

In my WinUI 3 app, whenever a `RichTextBlock` is on the page and the user types `F7`, a caret browsing dialog opens up. Since F7 has other functionality in my app, I would like to suppress this. Any ideas how to achieve this?
[image: WinUI 3 caret browsing dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```xml
<RichTextBlock IsTextSelectionEnabled="False">
```

did the trick.